# Подмена сайта в зависимости от условий nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Нужно подменять сайт в зависимости от гео посетителя.

```
if ($geoip_country_code = RU ) {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /RU/$1 last;
}
if ($geoip_country_code = US ) {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /EN/$1 last;
}
```

Так не выходит, 404 ошибка. Не силен в nginx, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось намного проще - root /html/path/$geoip_country;